# Workspace Tweak

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, 19.10, ubuntu-dock

I just switched over from Linux Mint 19.2 (best decision ever), and there is one difference between the Ubuntu workspaces and the Mint workspaces that I don't like. On Mint when I switched workspaces, the dock updated so only the windows in the particular workspace in focus were shown on the doc. In Ubuntu, the windows open throughout all workspaces are shown on the dock no matter which workspace is in focus.

Is there a way that I can make the Ubuntu dock behave like the Mint dock when switching workspaces?

I am on a Dell XPS13 9380 with Ubuntu 19.10. If you would like me to provide any additional information, please ask.

Comment: Maybe try https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/887/workspace-isolated-dash/

Comment: Perhaps you have a different app installed in Ubuntu to provide the Dock than Linux Mint used, and the different app works differently. Which program did you use to provide the Dock in Mint, and which app in Ubuntu? The Ubuntu Dock is shown as item #4 at https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-19-10  .Which release number of Mint was installed?

Comment: @K7AAY My ubuntu distro uses Gnome and mint uses cinnamon desktop. The mint version was 19.2 Tina.

Comment: Those are the Desktop Environments, not the Dock apps. Which program did you use to provide the Dock in Mint, and which app in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Terrance thank you! that's exactly what I wanted. If you want to respond to the thread with your solution I will make it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was posted as a comment by @Terrance under my original post:

"
 Maybe try extensions.gnome.org/extension/887/workspace-isolated-dash
"

I ran the command:

`dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/isolate-workspaces true`

and it works flawlessly.